# Where to place and execute a FileWatcher into a spring-boot project?

Tags: java, spring-boot, jobs

I already have a working fileWatcher with `WatchService`, this executes some logic when a new file is added in the predefined folder in my `application.properties`. But I do not know where is the best place to put it. Currently I placed in the main method, I think it's a bad idea leaved there.

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableAutoConfiguration(exclude = { DataSourceAutoConfiguration.class })
public class MyApplication {

    @Value("${routing.folder}")
    private static String ROUTING_FOLDER;

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        SpringApplication.run(MyApplication.class, args);
        Path dir = Paths.get(ROUTING_FOLDER);
        new SepaRoutingFilesWatcher(dir).processEvents();
    }

}
```

The class `SepaRoutingFilesWatcher` receives the folder and liste the new files placed in it. I'm also tried creating a `Job` with `@EnableBatchProcessing` that executes the function when the application starts, nevertheless I would like to do it in a clear way, for example from maven.